# How to stop an image auto resizing when the window is expanded

Tags: html, css, image, web, resize

I'm having an issue with my website http://www.tom-phelps.com/work 
I have only just noticed that when using a large monitor the top left image resizes itself and overlaps other content as the screen gets wider, although the lower image does not and they are both using exactly the same CSS and HTML set ups and I have tried adjusting the size of the first one. Both are .JPEGs, can anyone help me out with this? thanks

--Image that resizes itself--

```
.work1{
width: 100%;
min-width: 768px;
min-height:440px;


}

.image1{
width:35%;
float:left;
height:100%;
min-height:440px;
background-image:url(phelpsroofing2.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
margin-top:20px;
}
```

--Image that stays the same--

```
.work2{
width: 100%;
min-width: 768px;
min-height:440px;
background-color:#cccccc;
}

.image2{
width:35%;
float:right;
height:100%;
min-height:440px;
background-image:url(ipad2.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
margin-top:20px;

}
```

Comment: http://www.tom-phelps.com/work says page not found

Comment: Post your markup here.

Answer (score 0):

What would you like to happen exactly? An image with 100% width will scale, meaning the height will also adjust itself depending on how wide the image is.

If you want the image to scale but cap it, give it a max-width. If you want it to scale but not overlap the content below, give the container (which is .work1) an overflow: hidden;